# My React-Native navigation just wont style

Tags: react-native

I have an issue that no matter what I try, I just cannot get styling to work on my Stack with Drawer navigator. I've tried several examples and solutions but just none of them work, my navigation stays the default blue.

In my current code below, I've left 2 coloring options open - those two are of the many things I've tried before.

I hope that someone knows what's going on because I'm starting to get clueless.

```
const MainScreenNavigator = StackNavigator({
  'Home': {
    screen: Components.HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: <Components.StackHeader title='Home' navigation={navigation} />
    })
  },
  'Scan': {
    screen: Components.ScanScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: <Components.StackHeader title='Scan QR' navigation={navigation} />
    })
  },
  'LockInfo': {
    screen: Components.LockInfoScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: <Components.StackHeader title='Lock' navigation={navigation} />
    })
  },
});

const RootNavigator = DrawerNavigator ({
  Home: {
    screen: MainScreenNavigator,
  },
});

RootNavigator.navigationOptions = {
  contentOptions: {
    activeBackgroundColor: '#ff5976',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#000000'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ModalNavigator = StackNavigator(
{
 Main: { screen: Main },
 Login: { screen: Login },
},
{
 headerMode: 'none',
 mode: 'modal',
 navigationOptions: {
 gesturesEnabled: false,
},
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Screen-Navigation-Options

checkout this above link, search and add the required styling properties inside your own StackNavigator, headerStyle, headerTitleStyle, headerBackTitleStyle, headerTintColor and so on...

Also for DrawerNavigator, checkout this below link and replicate the code, styling properties for the same are provided.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer#DrawerNavigator

Also remove the single inverted commas from Home, Scan and LockInfo

Comment: I get an error : Route 'navigationOptions' should declare a screen when I implement it like your example, as: LockInfo: {
    screen: Components.LockInfoScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: <Components.StackHeader title='Lock' navigation={navigation} />
    })
  },
   navigationOptions: {
     gesturesEnabled: false,
     backgroundColor: '#000000'
  },